# Periodic solutions of non autonomous differential equation $\dot{x}(t)=x(t)(1+\cos(t))-x(t)^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Find all $2\pi$ periodic solutions (either constant or non-constant) of the nonautonomous equation

$\dot{x}=x(1+\cos(t))-x^3$.

I know that the only equilibria is $x=0$ which is a source.

Comment: But $x=\pm1$ are *not* equilibria, are they?

Comment: You're right, then is $x=0$ the only periodic orbit?

Comment: Why should they?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Why should $x=0$ be the only periodic orbit and why should this statement follow from my first comment?

Comment: @Did Btw, me neither understand your approach. Since the question has already been answered, could you shed more light on your idea?

Comment: @Evgeny Which "idea"? I do not recall having proposed any "approach" to solve this question, I merely underlined that the notion of equilibrium is not adequately describing $x=\pm1$ in the present situation since $x(t)=1$ for every $t$, for example, is not a solution (I believe you have the reputation needed to see the previous versions of a post, have you not?). Do you object to this (trivial) remark? If you are not, please explain your comment.

Comment: @Did Ah, sorry, I see now. Somehow I've read everything wrong and thought that your questions were directing OP towards some approach, but they were objections to some OP's guesses. Nevermind :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this as Bernoulli equation, set $u=r^{-2}$ then
$$
u'=-2r^{-3}r'=-2(1+\cos t)u+2
$$
which now can be nicely solved as a first order linear ODE.

$A(t)=e^{2(t+\sin t)}$, then $(A(t)u(t))'=2A(t)$,
$$
A(2\pi)u(2\pi)=u(0)+\int_0^{2\pi}A(s)ds 
$$
So for $u(2\pi)=u(0)$ you need
$$
u(0)=\frac{\int_0^{2\pi}e^{2(s+\sin s)}ds}{e^{4\pi}-1}=\frac12e^{2\sin(\theta·2\pi)},\quad\theta\in(0,1)
$$
which gives exactly one positive radius.

Comment: Great answer, its so clear!